# When a different radio button is checked on submission, it doesn't remember that checkbox when returning to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.EditSearchVM.SearchBy, "Id") <text> ID  &nbsp &nbsp</text>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.EditSearchVM.SearchBy, "CreationDate", new { @checked = "checked" }) <text> Creation Date  &nbsp &nbsp</text><br />
```

I have one selected by default but when I check the other one it should have that one still checked when returning from the controller.

Comment: Yo need to compare the controller code of what is working and what is not working and figure out what's the difference. You have the code so we can not even guess what could be the issue. The wild guess is that you are resetting the property value of model before sending it back to the view.

Comment: I have debugged it and the value is correct when it arrives to the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you also mentioned in the question first you need to create your viewModel. for example:

```
public class EditSearchVM
{
    public string SearchBy { get; set; }
    //Some other properties ....
}
```

To keep the example simple, I will use Home controller and Index. In your View you need to Create an HTML Form and pass the data to your view.

```
@model EditSearchVM
<form method="post" action="/Home/Index">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(r => r.SearchBy, "Id") ID
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(r => r.SearchBy, "CreationDate") CreationDate
    <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit the form" />
</form>
```

Inside of Home controller, in the Index (Get) action you need to set the default selected. There are many ways that you can do it. This one is one example.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     //Set the default selected
     var model =  new EditSearchVM (){ SearchBy = "CreationDate" };            
     return View(model);
}
```

Then you need the Post action. If you want to keep the current selected when you return the page you need to pass the model as well. So your Post action will be this like:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(EditSearchVM model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Do something and redirect to proper controller and action
    }
    return View(model);
}
```